# insert large file to content from salesforce visualforce site page

Tags: force.com-sites, file-storage

Can I insert large files into content from Visualforce page enabled on sites?

I want to insert more than 50MB files. Can Vf page transfer more than 50mb file to controller for insertion?
Please share the code for the same. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

> With new Summer 14 you can insert upto 25MB of attachment data through Visualforce and hence upto 50 MB is still double margin and dont think its possible unless file is split into two of 25MB each .